# How to stop automatic redirect from Localhost to Live Site for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, xampp

I received Laravel 5.8 project from Client. 
When i extract all files and trying to open this files after config clear, cache clear and key generate its redirect me to live website.
Note : Database connected successfully complete.
I replaced previews .htaccess file inside code. I copied public/.htaccess file and paste it outside of public folder.
After this i updated composer files by composer update.

replace client .htaccess with public/.htaccess

Below my .htaccess file code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note : already tried to solve this problem with below command after change client .htaccess with public/.htaccess file code :

```
 php artisan config:cache
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan key:generate
 composer update
 composer dump-autoload
```

Thank you.

Comment: what's your app url in `.env` file??

Comment: APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: @zahidhasanemon APP_URL =localhost

Comment: Look for any `redirect` method call in the project files (maybe in the service providers/route files)

Comment: @mdexp nope. Nothing there for redirect method call.

Comment: I solved this problem . I just remove vendor folder. and update Composer its working now . Thanks Guys